# Powershell: Create users from file and create a directory on share

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello I am attempting to setup a script that imports a txt file of users, separates the firstname/last name, then creates the user in an OU.  This works however I attempted to add another command after it but still in the loop that creates a directory on the share since when i tried to tried to set the home directory for the user in the command, the home directory was set but the directory was never created.  Therefore I am attempting to add the create directory to this command but i get an error:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\test.user\Desktop\name.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $Split = $_.Split(" ");
    $given=$Split[0];
    $sur=$Split[1]; 
    $uname=$given + "." + $sur; 
    New-ADUser -GivenName $given -Surname $sur -Name ($given + " " + $sur) `
      -UserPrincipalName (($uname + "@" + "$env:userdnsdomain")).ToLower() `
      -path "OU=testou, DC=testdomain, DC=local" -SamAccountName ($uname).ToLower() `
      -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "pass-word1" `
      -Force) -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
      -Verbose New-Item -Path "\\testdomain.local\userdata\test users\$uname" -ItemType "directory"
}
```

`New-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Path' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values  to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3". At line:1 char:509`

I am unsure how to do it like how it recommends as i am new to scripting.  How could add the New-Item -Path command to the command so it creates the directory on the share so i can then set user home directories to it.  I may then try to implement setting the home directory into this command.  I tried to remove -Path since you can create directories without it but then it gave an error:
New-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'New-Item'.
At line:1 char:161

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please format your code and error messages. As it is now, this is barely readable

Comment: There are already sample scripts all over the web showing how to do this, as well as Youtube videos on the use case. Never run destructive ()New, Create, Update, Move, Delete, Rename code without proper validation. Test/validate results before real runs. -WhatIf/$Confirm:, look them up. Especially since you said this. ['I am unsure how to do it like how it recommends as i am new to scripting.'] You really should spend the needed time to get up to speed on PowerShell, and ADDS scripts with it. Youtube has plenty of videos to get you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While formatting your code for you, the issue is you're missing a `;`.  Here is the updated version.  Next time try not to one-liner it, it makes for a hell of a time to figure out what's going on.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\test.user\Desktop\name.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $Split = $_.Split(" ");
    $given=$Split[0];
    $sur=$Split[1]; 
    $uname=$given + "." + $sur; 
    New-ADUser -GivenName $given -Surname $sur -Name ($given + " " + $sur) `
      -UserPrincipalName (($uname + "@" + "$env:userdnsdomain")).ToLower() `
      -path "OU=testou, DC=testdomain, DC=local" -SamAccountName ($uname).ToLower() `
      -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "pass-word1" `
      -Force) -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
      -Verbose -WhatIf # Semi-colon here if you want it a one-liner, or new line for readability
    New-Item -Path "\\testdomain.local\userdata\test users\$uname" -ItemType "directory" -WhatIf
}
```

The `New-Item` needs to be on a new line, or a semi-colon needs to be after `-Verbose`.

**EDIT**

Added in -WhatIf per postanote's comments, and I agree.